# how to combine value of same tag in xml

Tags: c#, xml, tags

I'm new in XML and I having problem in combining 2 value in XML with the same tag name.

Example of XML,

```
 <point>
  <ref>
    <text>My name</text>
  </ref>
  <ref>
    <text>James</text>
  </ref>
 </point>
```

I want to get the output of "My name James".. any idea or solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supose Xml file is located at `C:\Temp\test.xml`

```
string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Temp\test.xml");

var xml = XElement.Parse(fileContent);

              //select every node with name 'text' regardless of their location in DOM
var values  = xml.XPathSelectElements("//text")
                 .Select(element => element.Value);

string result = string.Join(" ", values);

Console.WriteLine (result);
```

Prints

> My name James

If you want specific nodes at path `point/ref/text`, then use next `values` extractor

```
var values = xml.Descendants("ref")
                .Elements()
                .Where(node => node.Name == "text")
                .Select(node => node.Value);
```

Comment: Thanks... its works! But any idea on how to change the xml file into the string str format that shows in the code? any keyword or what so that I can study further?

Comment: @JerryGJ by `change` you mean read a file? You need to read a xml file, add xml node and convert to a string, right?

Comment: yep.. fully convert the xml file into string. I trying with the XmlTextReader but currently still fail.. still trying. Any suggestion other than this method?